# React / JavaScript - Optional hiding for menu options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

THere's a `Menu` on my `UI` and what im trying to achieve is  to `provide an optional hiding` for each specified `menu` `item`, all that based on logged user `role`.

In my `Menu` component im iterating through `MenuItems` and showing/hiding them based on their `item.Hide` property:

Structure of menu item array `MenuItems[]` is as following:

```
const MenuItems[] = [
  {
     label: ''
     icon: ''
     hide: showOrHideByUserRole(userRole, ItemIDs.search)    // I added this property
  },
  {
     label: ''
     icon: ''
     hide: showOrHideByUserRole(userRole, ItemIDs.about)    // I added this property
  },
  {
     *etc*
  }
]
```

Of course there's `ItemIDs enum` which is only providing an `id` for a specific `item name` (string). And `userRole` *state*.

And here's my `showOrHideByUserRole` function which im concerned about:

```
function showOrHideByUserRole(roleName:string, itemID: number){
      switch (itemID) {

        case 1:
            if(roleName === 'AAA')
                return false;
            else if(roleName === 'BBB')
                return false;
            else
              return true;

        case 2:
            if(roleName === 'AAA')
                return true;
            else if(roleName === 'BBB')
                return false;
            else
              return true;

        case 3:
            if(roleName === 'AAA')
                return false;
            else if(roleName === 'BBB')
                return false;
            else
              return true;

        case 4:
            if(roleName === 'AAA')
                return false;
            else if(roleName === 'BBB')
                return false;
            else
              return true;

        case 5:
            if(roleName === 'AAA')
                return false;
            else if(roleName === 'BBB')
                return false;
            else
              return true;

        default:
          return true;
          
      }
  }
```

As you can see this looks kind of ugly (to me at least?) and im wondering if there's a prettier/better way to do what I want?

What needs to be considered is future expansion `role`-wise. Meaning there might be more roles in the future.

Comment: @RobertTerrell  i had a typo but i edited it few min ago. Not sure if you're talking about that or not. Please check again and clarify?

Comment: understood I have offered what I believe is a pretty solid option and leaves room for the expansion of roles

Answer (score 1):

```
function showOrHideByUserRole(roleName, itemID) {
  switch (itemID) {
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 1:
      if (roleName === 'AAA' || roleName === ' BBB') return false
      else return true
    case 2:
      if (roleName === 'AAA') return true
      else if (roleName === 'BBB') return false
      else return true

    default:
      return true
  }
}
```

it appears you have multiple cases returning the same thing so you could stack your cases that return similar outcomes like what is done above

EDIT: previous answer missed a couple like cases so I have edited the answer as a result

Comment: This looks better than how i did it. Thank you for the suggestion. Will see if anyone comes up with a better idea.